# Prove a planar graph with an arbitrary extra edge can be embedded on a torus

Tags: graph-theory

I want to prove the any two points x,y can be placed on the exterior face the same time. But i have no idea.

If you know, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the original graph is planar, you can embed it into a plane.
Let $uv$ be the extra edge.  Pick a face $f_u$ incident with $u$ and a face $f_v$ incident with $v$. Then you can add a handle to the plane such that one end is in $f_u$ and the other in $f_v$. Using this handle, you can draw an arc from $u$, into $f_u$, along the handle, into $f_v$, to $v$. Finally, add a point to infinity to turn your plane-with-handle into a sphere-with-handle, aka torus.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.

Comment: I didn’t realize such a topology relation between torus and sphere.